# Remove only exact number of repeat matches between two files

Tags: bash, awk, grep, duplicates, compare

I want to get the remaining difference between two files that have redundant entries.

**File1.txt:**

```
Data1
Data1
Data2
Data2
Data3
Data3
Data3
Data3
Data4
Data5
Data6
Data6
```

and

**File2.txt:**

```
Data1
Data2
Data2
Data3
Data3
Data4
Data5
Data6
```

**Finalfile.txt:**

```
Data1
Data3
Data3
Data6
```

In other words: if an entry shows up n times in file 1 and m times in file 2 then, the final file should contain the n-m entries.
Ie: See there are four entries of **Data3** in File1.txt and only two entries in File2.txt, therefore the Finalfile.txt has 2 occurances of **Data3**.

I've tried:

```
grep -v -f File1.txt File2.txt > Finalfile.txt
```

but it give the absolute differences.

Comment: Why is `Data4` shown in final output when both files have exactly one line of `Data4` ?

Comment: Are the files sorted (as your examples suggest)? If not, would it matter if the output is?

Comment: `comm -23 File{1,2}.txt` or, if your files are not sorted, `comm -23 <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)`. See my answer for the details.

Comment: You described what to output if "foo" appears more times in file1 than in file2 but what should be output if "foo" appears more times in file2 than in file1?

Comment: @anubhava, youre right, ive edit it now.

Comment: @pmf not sorted and sorting does not matter.

Comment: @EdMorton in my particular situation, File2 will always have less than File1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use this 2 pass `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '
NR == FNR {
   ++fq[$1]
   next
}
{
   --fq[$1]
}
END {
   for (s in fq)
      for (i = 1; i <= fq[s]; ++i)
         print s
}' file1 file2

Data1
Data3
Data3
Data6
```

Answer (score 5):

another minimalist `awk`

algorithm is multiset difference: `file1 \ file2`.  Doesn't require sorted order.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} --a[$1]<0' file2 file1

Data1
Data3
Data3
Data6
```

Note that in your desired output Data4 should not be there!

Comment: clean and nice ++

Answer (score 4):

If your files are sorted you can try:

```
$ comm -23 File1.txt File2.txt

Data1
Data3
Data3
Data6
```

By default `comm` prints 3 columns:

- lines unique to FILE1,
- lines unique to FILE2,
- lines that appear in both files.

The `-23` option suppresses the lines unique to FILE2 and the lines that appear in both files. See `man comm` for the details. Note that if a line appears more times in `File2.txt` than in `File1.txt` it will not be printed.

If your files are not sorted yet you can try:

```
$ sort File1.txt | comm -23 - <(sort File2.txt)
```

The first `comm` input file is `-` (the standard input), that is, the standard output of `sort File1.txt`. The second is the `<(sort File2.txt)` process substitution, that presents the standard output of `sort File2.txt` as a regular named file.

Comment: nice solution specially `comm` thnx ++

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of `sort` and `diff` with `grep`:

```
diff <(sort test1.txt) <(sort test2.txt) | grep -Po '^< \K.*'
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`^` : Beginning of the line.
`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

**See also:**

- [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html)
- [`diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/diff-Options.html)

Comment: If you use `sed -n 's/^< //p'` instead of `grep -Po '^< \K.*'` then it'll work on any Unix box rather than just those that have GNU grep.

Comment: reinventing `comm`...

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please only, try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  file1Count[$1]++
  next
}
{
  file2Count[$1]++
}
END{
  for(i in file1Count){
     diff=file1Count[i]-file2Count[i]
     if(diff>0){
        while(++j<=diff){
           print i
        }
        j=0
     }
  }
}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -lne 'BEGIN{cnt1,cnt2=[0,1].map{|_| Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = 0} } }
if $<.file.lineno == $<.lineno then
    cnt1[$_]+=1
else
    cnt2[$_]+=1
end

END{
puts cnt1.select{|k,v| cnt2.has_key?(k) && cnt1[k]>cnt2[k]}.
    map{|k,v| ([k]*(cnt1[k]-cnt2[k])).join("\n")}  
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Prints:

```
Data1
Data3
Data3
Data6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with Perl :

```
perl -lane '
         BEGIN{%fq=()};
         $ARGV eq "File1.txt" ? ++$fq{$F[0]} : --$fq{$F[0]};
         END{foreach $s (sort keys %fq)
         {for($i=1;$i<=$fq{$s};++$i){print $s}}}' File1.txt File2.txt
```

Output

```
Data1
Data3
Data3
Data6
```